# kickstart/preseed Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop (needs eMMC kernel support)

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, kernel, preseed, unattended-upgrades

There are plenty of answers for this using the server install but due to the lack of eMMC storage support during the install its insufficient for my needs. My ultimate goal is to do install's of this OS completely unattended.

If the question literally has no answer due to the lack of kickstart/preseed support is there any possible way to recompile the kernel for server with eMMC support?

I have found that the preseed files have a minor effect during the desktop install. For instance when I enter the fullname & username the fields are auto filled during the prompts but not the hostname or the password. I have adjusted just about every possible step of the preseed file and thats the only thing it seems to work on.

Currently I have a mix of adjusting grub.cfg, editing the preseed file and using UCK to configure the install to include extra packages and place additional files in the OS for later deployment use.